# Whats the difference between declaring a lazy var and a let when accessing on the initializer?

Tags: swift, lazy-evaluation, var, let

I was wondering what is the difference between a lazy var and a let when they're going to be used on the class initializer or on the very first block of the class, something like:

```
lazy var label : UILabel = UILabel()

override func viewDidLoad() {

   super.viewDidLoad()
   label.text = "hey"
}
```

vs

```
let label : UILabel = UILabel()

override func viewDidLoad() {

   super.viewDidLoad()
   label.text = "hey"
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

- The `let` constant is created during the initialization of the enclosing object and is **im**mutable.
- The `lazy var`iable is created at the moment it is being accessed the first time and is mutable.

Comment: I know that, but I wanted to know the difference when they are both accessed on the initializer too.

Comment: As written in my answer, the former is initialized instantly with the controller, the latter when `viewDidLoad` is called.

Answer (score 1):

The `lazy` keyword will cause the label to be intialized only when it is used within your program, that is, when label.text is called.

The `let` keyword will initialize your label right when the program steps through that line of code.

Comment: Yes, but is there any difference between both if they’re being accessed on the class initializer?